# Execute Python files in windows 7 CMD

Tags: python

I have installed python 32 package to the

> C:\python32

I have also set the path:

> PYTHONPATH | C:\Python32\Lib;C:\Python32\DLLs;C:\Python32\Lib\lib-tk;

but I still cannot run files typing "python file.py" using cmd.
What else should i do?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your Python's installation directory to `PATH`: http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable

Comment: Thank you, i will try setting the PATH :)

Answer (score 1):

From cmd, do `path %path%;c:\python32` - this will append the python dir to the environment path.

Gui way here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Also, this for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)